# If $\ A,B\ $ are countable, nowhere dense subsets of $\ \mathbb{R},\ $ and $\ A\ $ is bounded, then is $\ A+B\ $ nowhere dense in $\ \mathbb{R}\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

**The question:**

> If $\ A,B\ $ are countable, nowhere dense subsets of $\ \mathbb{R},\
> $ and furthermore $\ A\ $ is bounded, then is $\ A+B = \{a+b:\ a\in
> A,\ b\in B \}\ $ nowhere dense in $\ \mathbb{R}\ ?$

Firstly, I know from another question I asked that if $\ C\ $ is the ternary Cantor set, then $\ C + C = [0,2].\ $ $\ C\ $ is nowhere dense. However, it is uncountable, and this question is about **countable** nowhere dense subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}. $

Secondly, without the boundedness restriction, we could let $\ \{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ be an enumeration of the rationals between $\ 0\ $ and $\ \frac{1}{10}.\ $ Then if we let $\ A = \{ 1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\alpha_1}{2},\ 2+ \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{\alpha_2}{2},\ 3+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{\alpha_3}{2},\ \ldots\}\ $ and $\ B = \{ -1-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\alpha_1}{2},\ -2- \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{\alpha_2}{2},\ -3- \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{\alpha_3}{2},\ \ldots\},\ $ then $\ \{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ \subset A+B,\ $ and so $\ A+B\ $ is dense in $\ \left[ 0, \frac{1}{10}\right].$

But with the restriction of $\ A\ $ being bounded, I don't think this process works without making $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ both dense somewhere in $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ which is not allowed, but I am not sure.

Obviously both $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ must have limit points due to $\ B-W,\ $ but I don't see how this helps answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $A$ and $B$ being the set of the rationals in the Cantor set is a counterexample. $\overline{\Bbb Q\cap C}=C$, therefore $$\overline{(\Bbb Q\cap C)+(\Bbb Q\cap C)}\supseteq C+C= [0,2].$$

Comment: What rationals are in the Cantor set other than $\ \frac{1}{4}\ $ and why? I think I have poor intuition of this...

Comment: From another question I just found that the rationals in the Cantor set are anything whose ternary expansion repeats and has only 0s and 2s (but that doesn't say what the denominators are. Denominators of rationals in the Cantor set are on a page at OEIS). But it's still not clear to me why $\overline{\Bbb Q\cap C}=C$ ?

Comment: $0$ and $1$, for instance. I don't know off the top of my head if $\frac14\in C$. The extremal points of the open intervals you remove at each step are all rational and they are elements of $C$. Moreover, if you have a finite sequence $0< n_1< n_2<\cdots <n_k$, then $\sum_{j=1}^k 2\cdot 3^{-n_j}\in C$.

Comment: Yes, every point in Cantor's set is a limit of endpoints. Also of points with finite ternary expansion.

Comment: Yes I just realised that. All the endpoints are rational, so it seems reasonable that every member of the cantor set should be the limit of a sequence of endpoints. $\frac{1}{4}\in C,\ $ from wikipedia for example, although $\frac{1}{4}\ $ is not one of the endpoints... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Composition

Comment: @AdamRubinson Don't change my answer. I wrote $\supseteq$ for a specific reason: that I did not want to address why $\overline{A+B}\supseteq \overline A+\overline B$ holds.

Comment: Yes, ok. I misunderstood why you wrote what you wrote, but now I get it. I was just trying to make sense of what you wrote but now I realise my lines of thinking was probably wrong. But I probably shouldn't change your answer anyway, so sorry for that.